# Web Page aspx issue

Tags: asp.net, html

I'm trying to access a the page below but I'm getting the following error:

Offending URL: http://www.mockcourt.org.uk/default.aspx

> Source: App_Web_azvlqjha
>
> Message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Stack
>   trace: at _Default.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) at
>   System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object
>   o, Object t, EventArgs e) at
>   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender,
>   EventArgs e) at System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

Does anyone know what is causing this?

Thanks
Ross

Comment: Elves, in your undercroft. Either that or their page is broken.

Comment: It is because of some error in Page_Load  event. Debug to find the error n the application or provide more details

Answer (score 0):

Theres not enough information to say exactly, but at a guess there is an object being referenced in your `Page_Load` method which does not exist. Perhaps you have something like:

```
Page.FindControl("ID_Here")
```

Where there is no control with the ID: `ID_HERE`